# Search NSFetchedResults by changing Settings in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have read a lot of content and watched several tutorials on how to search Core Data by using a search bar however I have not yet seen anything for how to change a the sort descriptor by passing a setting from a `Settings` view to the `Table View`.

I have a `search` bar button item that when pressed goes to a `SearchSettingsVC`. The views communicate by passing boolean's from one VC to the other and vise-versa. The problem is that the table is not corresponding accordingly by changing the TableVC order - (I have tried calling self.tableview beginUpdates, self.tableview reload, self fetchedResultsController among other things).

**The point is to reorder the TableVC results, not to present only specific results like a predicate does**

I have created a delegate for the SettingsVC so that I can pass boolean value to the SettingsVC which is then capable of returning a different changed value if there are any changes.

The problem is that I cannot manage to get the table view (or prehaps even the fetched results) to update.

Here is my code for my `-(NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultsController` method:

```
// return if already initialized
if (self.fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return self.fetchedResultsController;
}

if (dateSearch == true){

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    // the entity to fetch
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    // how to sort the data
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"addDate" ascending:YES];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                         managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                                           sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                    cacheName:nil];

    // fetch the data
    NSError *e = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&e]) {
        NSLog(@"fetch error(Date): %@", e );
        abort();
    }

    NSLog(@"Dates loaded");
}

if (mostAmount == true){

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    // the entity to fetch
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    // how to sort the data
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"amount" ascending:NO];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                         managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                                           sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                    cacheName:nil];

    // fetch the data
    NSError *e = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&e]) {
        NSLog(@"fetch error (Most Fuel): %@", e);
        abort();
    }

    NSLog(@"Amount loaded");

}

else{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    // the entity to fetch
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    // how to sort the data
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"addDate" ascending:YES];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

    // fetch the data
    NSError *e = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&e]) {
        NSLog(@"fetch error(Date): %@", e );
        abort();
    }

    NSLog(@"Defualt loaded");
}

return self.fetchedResultsController;
```

I required a default because at the beginning when I initialise the booleans in the TableVC to false they can be updated when I go to my settings VC.

My SearchSettingsVC has UISwitches that change the values from true to false (and vice-versa) which successfully update the equivalent booleans in the TableVC as represented when I return to the SearchSettingsVC.

My `prepareForSegue` code in my TableVC

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"searchSettings"]){
    //pass new search settings in here
    SearchSelectionSettings * settingsVC = (SearchSelectionSettings *)segue.destinationViewController;

    settingsVC.delegate = self;
    settingsVC.dateSearch = dateSearch;
    settingsVC.mostAmount = mostAmount;
```

This is my closeSettings method which is located in my TableVC

```
#pragma mark - SettingsViewControllerDelegate methods
//record the settings changed in the settings view
//dismissViewController changes the screen
- (void)closeSettings:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Working?");

    dateSearch = ((SearchSelectionSettings *)sender).dateSearch;
    mostAmount = ((SearchSelectionSettings *)sender).mostAmount;


     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     [self FetchedResultsController];
     NSIndexPath * indexPath;
    [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Passing boolean values from one VC to other works perfectly. Getting the TableView to update according to the fetchedResults `if` statements does not, my switches in the SettingsVC are updated every time without any issues. Can anyone help or recommend a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opening lines of the `fetchedResultscontroller` getter, i.e.:

```
// return if already initialized
if (self.fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return self.fetchedResultsController;
}
```

mean that, once your fetchedResultsController has been created, the remaining code will not be executed when you access it.  A quick way to resolve your problem would therefore be to set `self.fetchedResultsController` to `nil` in your `closeSettings` method, and then reload your table view.  When the tableview reloads, it will access the `fetchedResultsController` again, and since it is now `nil`, the above code will be bypassed and your code will be used.

```
#pragma mark - SettingsViewControllerDelegate methods
//record the settings changed in the settings view
//dismissViewController changes the screen
- (void)closeSettings:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Working?");

    dateSearch = ((SearchSelectionSettings *)sender).dateSearch;
    mostAmount = ((SearchSelectionSettings *)sender).mostAmount;


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Alternatively, you can modify the fetchedResultsController's fetch and then get it to reperform the fetch:

```
#pragma mark - SettingsViewControllerDelegate methods
//record the settings changed in the settings view
//dismissViewController changes the screen
- (void)closeSettings:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Working?");

    dateSearch = ((SearchSelectionSettings *)sender).dateSearch;
    mostAmount = ((SearchSelectionSettings *)sender).mostAmount;


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Details"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort;
    if (dateSearch == true){
        sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"addDate" ascending:YES];
        NSLog(@"Dates loaded");
    } else if (mostAmount == true) {
        sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"amount" ascending:NO];
        NSLog(@"Amount loaded");
    } else {
        sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"addDate" ascending:YES];
        NSLog(@"Default loaded");
    }
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest = request;
    // fetch the data
    NSError *e = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&e]) {
        NSLog(@"fetch error (Most Fuel): %@", e);
        abort();
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

That way, you can simplify your fetchedResultsController code so it just loads the default.

Comment: If I ever meet you, I will gladly buy you a beverage for the following reasons:

1. Solution 2 in your answer worked.

2. You gave an answer that was explained and demonstrated with code (the combination of the two is not that common I am finding where people simply just give a worded answer without a working answer).

3. You answered with multiple relevant suggestions.

Many thanks.